# WAR Deploy on tomcat fails with "illegal type in constant pool"

Tags: java

I am trying to deploy a war on tomcat and it is failing with "illegal type in constant pool" on a Drools class

This doesn't happen with the same war on other PCs with similar setups (tomcat7.0.42+jdk8), but persists if I try to deploy on fresh instances of tomcat on my pc.

Seems like there is something wrong with my JVM. any ideas?

Comment: Please post the exact error message, or java exception

Comment: Don't have the stacktrace available at the moment, but this is the exception msg (the class is part of the drools jar):
VerifyError: (class: KnowledgeBase, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Illegal type in constant pool.

Comment: VerifyError usually indicates that you may have same class in more than one jar and the jar (with wrong version) is shadowing the other (with right version). Though, error on deplo ying on fresh Tomcat still remains a mystery. Try this, if you are using the installer version, uninstall it and delete the tomcat directory. Take the zip archive and use it to redeploy. In addition, check if you have any CLASSPATH entries in your environment, that also could be pointing to an older version of the Drools jar

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like there is something wrong with my JVM. any ideas?

A broken JVM installation is one possibility.  A couple of others are:

- a broken Tomcat installation,
- a damaged WAR file, or
- a hardware fault.

---

Or it could be an issue with Drools on Java 8.  For example:

- https://github.com/rayploski/metrics/issues/1
- https://www.java.net/forum/topic/jdk/java-se-snapshots-project-feedback/drools-stop-working-java-8